# How to get index of different top-k at each row in a 2D tensor in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

Given:

- a positive integer tensor A: (batch_size, N) in which zero is the smallest value. For example:

```
tensor([[4, 3, 1, 4, 2],
        [0, 0, 2, 3, 4],
        [4, 4, 3, 0, 3]])
```

I want get the index of different k of k-th largest value at each row?

- k is a list of `batch_size` elements are chosen randomly in which its values only express only 2 cases:
  first is largest (so k = 1) second is the smallest but ignore zero, e.g. if the row is [2,3,4,0] so the smallest index is 0 (value 2). (with possibility = 0.7 for largest and 0.3 for smallest)

With the example above, `if k = [1,0,0]` (1 means get largest, 0 mean smallest) then the output indices will be

`output = [0, 2, 2]` the correspond values are `[4, 2,3]`

Notes: please vectorize these calculations.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Oh I just had an idea when I read your comment ; ). Actually I stucked at the smallest part. What if I create a list the number of distinct value of each row ignore zero? then the smallest k = number of distinct value

Comment: But haven't figured out the way to do that with vectorization (using torch.top doesnt allow pass list k )

Comment: Or I just need to mask zero by the possible max + 1 when find the smallest . As actually I know the possible max value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this

```py
import torch

x = torch.tensor([[4, 3, 1, 4, 2],
                  [0, 0, 2, 3, 4],
                  [4, 4, 3, 0, 3]]).float() # float required for later ops

k = torch.tensor([1, 0, 0]).long()

# set 0 to -1, ie [1, -1, -1]
k_sign = k + (-1 * (k==0).float())

# flip sign for rows where we want the smallest nonzero index
x_signed = x * k_sign.unsqueeze(1)

# fill zeros with -inf
x_filled = x_signed.masked_fill(x==0, float('-inf'))

# grab topk index of each row
_, output = x_filled.topk(1, dim=1)

output = output.squeeze()

output
> tensor([0, 2, 2])
```